# Using jQuery in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Newbie to WP/jQuery.

I've created a simple form in WP. Not using a plugin, just hand-coded it.

I'm now trying to pass data from one form field to another using jQuery.

I've checked that jQuery library is available to page and I have used wp_enqueue_script to also load a custom.js file.

HTML (in WP page):

```
<input id="field_1" name="field_1">

<input id="field_2" name="field_2">
```

jQuery (in custom.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#field_1').change(function () {
        $('#field_2').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

I have tested the code in a HTML page (outside of WP and it definitely works.

I wonder if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: go to view source of page and check jQuery file is included or not on the page

Comment: Hi Deep Kakkar, I checked page source. The custom.js file is being loaded  along with other JS files just before closing </body> tag.

Comment: Finally tracked down the problem. I had a syntax error in an input id name (hence the 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null'). Many thanks to everyone who offered help.

Answer (score 0):

> The tricky thing is this particular copy of jQuery is in compatibility mode by default. That means that the typical '$' shortcut for jQuery doesn't work, so it doesn't conflict with any other JavaScript libraries that use the dollar sign also, like MooTools or Prototype.

Taken From: https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

You can use `jQuery` as follow:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#field_1').change(function () {
        $('#field_2').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

> The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the noConflict() mode (see wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js). This is to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link.

In the noConflict() mode, the global $ shortcut for jQuery is not available

Docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: Hi Tushar, Thanks for responding. Tried this but no luck. It doesn't work.

Comment: Two errors: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null (in main.js)

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (in jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:2)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking whether you have loaded the jQuery files properly. You can check whether the function is firing or not by adding `console.log(message)` before and after the function just to test it out. Check console by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I on Chrome.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    console.log('jQuery initialized'); //check 1 - jQuery included

    $('#field_1').change(function () {
        $('#field_2').val($(this).val());
        console.log('function fired'); //check 2 - value changed
    });

});
```

You can also try including jQuery by CDN as alternatives in the HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad!

Finally tracked down the problem. I had a syntax error in an input id name (hence the 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null').

Thanks to all those who provided assistance.

Much appreciated!